# FishPig WordPress, filter category into widget

Tags: magento-1.9, category, filter, third-party-module, wordpress

I need to show in the sidebar determinate category and its children through category widget

The file starts with :

```
    <?php $categories = $this->getCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
    <div class="block block-blog block-blog-categories">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getTitle()): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></span></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul class="level0" id="wp-category-list">
                <?php if ($this->getDropdown()): ?>
                    <li class="level0 item">
                        <select name="blog-archive-dropdown" onchange="setLocation(this.value);">
                            <option value="<?php echo $this->helper('wordpress')->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Select Category') ?></option>
                            <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
```

How filter by category term or ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution

in the foreach insert this condition

```
<?php if ($category->getSlug() === 'myslugcategory'): ?>
```

the complete foreach is

```
                    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                <?php if ($category->getSlug() === 'myslugcategory'): ?>
                    <li class="level0 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a  class="level0" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>">
                            <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
                        </a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $category->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->getHierarchical()): ?>
                            <?php $children = $category->getChildrenTerms() ?>
                            <?php if (count($children) > 0): ?>
                                <ul class="level1">
                                    <?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
                                        <?php if ($child->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                                        <li class="level1 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please accept this answer as correct if this works for you. it will help someone to know the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please update the code template`/wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml` to include a 3rd level categories means children categories. I have done by following code.

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <li class="level0 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
        <a  class="level0" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName() ?>">
            <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
        </a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $category->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getHierarchical()): ?>
            <?php $children = $children = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($children) > 0): ?>
                <ul class="level1">
                    <?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
                        <?php if ($child->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                        <li class="level1 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                            &raquo; <a href="<?php echo $child->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                      <?php $children2 = $children2 = $child->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                      <?php if (count($children2) > 0): ?>
                                          <ul class="level2">
                                              <?php foreach($children2 as $child2): ?>
                                                  <?php if ($child2->getPostCount() > 0): ?>
                                                      <li class="level12 item<?php if ($this->isCurrentCategory($child2)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                                          &raquo; <a href="<?php echo $child2->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $child2->getName() ?>" class="level1"><?php echo $child2->getName() ?></a><?php if ($this->getCount()): ?> (<?php echo $child2->getPostCount() ?>)<?php endif; ?>
                                                      </li>
                                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                              <?php endforeach; ?>
                                          </ul>
                                      <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: vah vishavas vah

Comment: I not need include 3rd level
I need display only one category with it children

Comment: @yavonz15 you can remove the last foreach and correspondent code if you don't want to include 3rd level categories. You can modify same code as per your need.

Comment: @yavonz15 this link might help you: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/advanced-custom-coding/
Btw, your question seems to be something different than your comments.